# How do I specify an include directory in ADA GPS

Tags: ada, gnat-gps

I was given an Ada source file from a co-worker to include in an existing project.  This source file wants to include the win32.ads which I see in c:\gnatpro\include\win32ada . But my installation of GnatPro doesn't look into this folder area, only the version-specific c:\gnatpro\6.2.2...  I'm not sure what I need to change to force the build tools to see c:\gnatpro\include as well (if it was C/C++ I'd add -i).

Any suggestions on how to modify my build command to include c:\gnatpro\include ?

Comment: If you are using GNATpro you should be able to get pro support from Adacore, and pro support is very good. That said ... what build command? You mention GPS, I’d expect you to be using a project file. But if you’re using `gnatmake` or `gprbuild` , then you can use `-Idir` just like in C.

Comment: And I’m pretty sure that the C equivalent is `-I`, not `-i`.

Comment: `-Idir` did not work (gprbuild: illegal option on the command line).

Comment: No more it does, sorry. You might be able to use `-cargs -Idir` at the end of the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the environment variable `ADA_INCLUDE_PATH=dir` to include the folder into the build process.